# PostConstruct called twice

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple Spring class annotated with `@Component`, which contains a method annotated with `javax.annotation.PostConstruct`:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientRegistrationService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationService clientRegistrationService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init_this() {
   .     System.out.println("Passed here"); 
        for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            System.out.println(ste);
        }
        clientRegistrationService.listClientDetails(); // if I comment out this line, then I see "Passed here" only once, otherwise I see it two times in the logs.
    }
}
```

This method is called twice, and I don't understand why.
I have added a print of the stacktrace as described above, and I get the same stacktrace both times:

```
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
*init_this
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:309)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:415)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1677)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:494)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:316)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:757)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:377)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:138)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:465)
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:451)
```

When I run a test (which was already there, I just added this new component) annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, the 'Passed here' is logged twice. However it doesn't happen when I launch the application (not the test).

What could cause this ?

Comment: looks like 2 beans of this class are created. One from @component

Comment: any other annotation do you have on class?

Comment: This is a class I have recently added. I have searched everywhere in the project for the name of the class, it appears only in the file I created, which contains this init method.

Comment: Just @Slf4j, but I doubt it's relevant

Comment: You are running a test, possibly one with `@DirtiesContext` or with a different configuration leading to starting things twice.

Comment: I am indeed running a test annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, sorry I forgot to mention that. I don't see a @DirtiesContext though

Comment: Please ad the test(s) you are running, without those this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: I don't think the test is related, all it does it fire up the Spring context initialization with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. I have however added the full component, with a comment explaining which line seems to be the issue.